# Tensorflow issue with conversion of type numpy.float64 to int

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I'm creating a very basic AI with Tensorflow, and am using the code from the official docs/tutorial. Here's my full code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat', 'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']

train_images = train_images / 255.0
train_labels = train_labels / 255.0

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
for i in range(25):
    plt.subplot(5,5,i+1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(train_images[i], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    plt.xlabel(class_names[train_labels[i]])
plt.show()
```

The issue is on this line:

```
plt.xlabel(class_names[train_labels[i]])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not numpy.float64
```

No problem, change the `numpy.float64` to `int` using `.item()`

```
plt.xlabel(class_names[train_labels[i.item()]])
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'item'
```

Was it an `int` in the first place?

This is running on Python 3.7, with Tensorflow 1.13.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by

```
train_labels = train_labels / 255.0
```

`train_labels` is a ndarray of labels. By dividing it to 255, the resulting ndarray contains float numbers. Therefore a floating number is used as an index for `class_names` resulting to the first error.

> list indices must be integers or slices, not numpy.float64

To convert a numpy array `x` to int, here is the way to go: `x.astype(int)`. But in this case doing so will create an array with all values to 0.

A fix is to remove the line identified above:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat', 'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']

train_images = train_images / 255.0
# train_labels = train_labels / 255.0

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
for i in range(25):
    print(train_labels[i], train_images.shape, train_labels.shape, type(train_labels))
    plt.subplot(5,5,i+1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(train_images[i], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    plt.xlabel(class_names[train_labels[i]])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Normalization (division by 255 in this case) is what is usually necessary to do with features, and not with labels, for labels try to use [One hot encoding](https://hackernoon.com/what-is-one-hot-encoding-why-and-when-do-you-have-to-use-it-e3c6186d008f).